# Logic of array with structures

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have difficulty implementing the new employee introduction logic in the code below. By determining the new quantity and relocating the vector based on it, the first new employee is showing up early or late or the program is terminating.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct {
char * name;
char * email;
int age;
}Employee;

   int main () {

 int i, option, employeeInitialQuantity, newEmployeeQuantity;

 printf ("How many employees would you like to register?");
scanf ("%d", &employeeInitialQuantity);
Employee *employees = malloc (employeeInitialQuantity * sizeof (Employee));

 for (i = 0; i < employeeInitialQuantity; i++) {

    employees [i] .name = malloc (35);
    printf ("\nType employee name %d:", i);
    scanf ("%34s", employees[i].name);
    printf ("\n%s", employees [i].name);
    employees [i] .email = malloc (35);
    printf ("\nEnter Employee Email% d:", i);
    scanf ("%34s", employees [i].email);
    printf ("\n%s", employees [i].email);
    printf ("\nEnter employee age %d:", i);
    scanf ("%d", & employees [i].age);
    printf ("\n%d", employees [i].age);
}



    while (1) {

     printf ("1.Register more employees \n");
     printf ("2.List employees \n");
     printf ("3.Edit employee data \n");
     printf ("4.Delete Employee \n");
     scanf ("%d", &option);

     if (option == 1) {

    printf ("Do you want to register how many more employees?");
    scanf ("%d", &newEmployeeQuantity);


   employees = (Employee *) realloc (employees, newEmployeeQuantity * sizeof (Employee));

   for (i =  employeeInitialQuantity; i <= newEmployeeQuantity; i ++) {

  employees [i] .name = malloc (35);
   printf ("\nType employee name% d:", i);
   scanf ("%34s", employees [i] .name);
   printf ("\n%s", employees [i] .name);
   employees [i] .email = malloc (35);
   printf ("\nEnter Employee Email %d:", i);
   scanf ("%34s", employees [i].email);
   printf ("\n%s", employees [i].email);
   printf ("\nEnter employee age %d:", i);
   scanf ("%d", & employees[i] .age);
   printf ("\n%d", employees[i].age);
}
        employeeInitialQuantity = (employeeInitialQuantity + newEmployeeQuantity) -1;

}




 else if (option == 3) {

       printf ("Enter the employee number you wish to edit:");
       int number;
       scanf ("%d", & number);
       printf ("Enter new employee name% d:", number);
       scanf ("%34s", employees [number] .name);
       printf ("Enter new employee email% d:", number);
       scanf ("%34s", employees [number] .email);
       printf ("Enter new employee age %d:", number);
       scanf ("%d\n", & employees [number]. age);

 }
```

}

```
  return 0;
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh8QE.jpg)

I am trying to implement this statement:

Make a program that manages employees (name, age, email). The program should display a User Menu,
with the following options:

1. Register

A. The program should allow the inclusion of new employees, asking the user how many he wants include and register them in an array of employees;

B. It is noteworthy that the array of employees should be allocated as needed, avoiding
waste of memory;

C. The name and email strings must also be dynamically allocated, as should the array of
employees.

2. List

A. The program should display the list of registered employees, one on each line, separated by “------
--------------------- ". The listing should display on each line the name, email and age of the
as follows: “Name - email@gmail.com - 25”.

3. Edit:

A. The program should allow editing of a particular employee. To do so, editing should be permitted.
from an employee from their index in the employee array, or from searching by name or
employee's email.

4. Delete

A. The program should allow the exclusion of a particular employee. To this end, it should be allowed to
deleting an employee from their index in the employee array, or from searching by
employee's name.

B. After deleting the employee the array should be rearranged so that it has no "holes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't reallocated correctly, in the second argument or realloc, you need to give total memory you want, not just the additional memory

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    char *email;
    int age;
} Employee;

int main ()
{
    int i, option, employeeInitialQuantity, newEmployeeQuantity;

    printf("How many employees would you like to register?");
    scanf("%d", &employeeInitialQuantity);
    Employee *employees = malloc(employeeInitialQuantity * sizeof (Employee));

    for (i = 0; i < employeeInitialQuantity; i++)
    {
        employees[i].name = malloc(35);
        printf("\nType employee name %d:", i);
        scanf("%34s", employees[i].name);
        printf("\n%s", employees[i].name);
        employees[i].email = malloc(35);
        printf("\nEnter Employee Email %d:", i);
        scanf("%34s", employees[i].email);
        printf("\n%s", employees[i].email);
        printf("\nEnter employee age %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &employees[i].age);
        printf("\n%d\n\n", employees[i].age);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        printf("1.Register more employees \n");
        printf("2.List employees \n");
        printf("3.Edit employee data \n");
        printf("4.Delete Employee \n");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        if (option == 1)
        {
            printf("Do you want to register how many more employees?");
            scanf("%d", &newEmployeeQuantity);

            employees = (Employee *)realloc(employees, (employeeInitialQuantity + newEmployeeQuantity) * sizeof(Employee));

            for (i =  employeeInitialQuantity; i < (employeeInitialQuantity + newEmployeeQuantity); i ++)
            {
                employees[i].name = malloc(35);
                printf("\nType employee name% d:", i);
                scanf("%34s", employees[i].name);
                printf("\n%s", employees[i].name);
                employees[i].email = malloc(35);
                printf("\nEnter Employee Email %d:", i);
                scanf("%34s", employees[i].email);
                printf("\n%s", employees[i].email);
                printf("\nEnter employee age %d:", i);
                scanf("%d", &employees[i].age);
                printf("\n%d\n\n", employees[i].age);
            }
            employeeInitialQuantity = (employeeInitialQuantity + newEmployeeQuantity);
        }

        else if (option == 3)
        {
            printf ("Enter the employee number you wish to edit:");
            int number;
            scanf ("%d", & number);
            printf ("Enter new employee name% d:", number);
            scanf ("%34s", employees[number].name);
            printf ("Enter new employee email% d:", number);
            scanf ("%34s", employees[number].email);
            printf ("Enter new employee age %d:", number);
            scanf ("%d\n", &employees[number].age);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```